# Generating one-time-only security tokens from UUID or HMAC/JWT/hash?

Tags: security, authentication, hash, jwt, hmac

I'm build the backend for a web app. When a new user goes to the site and clicks the **Sign Up** button, they'll fill out a super simple form asking them for their username + password and they'll submit. This prompts the server to send a verification email to that email address. They'll then check their email, click a link (which verifies their email) and then be routed to the login page so they can sign in if they choose.

In order to verify their email, when the server generates the email it will need to create (and store) a **verification token** (likely a UUID) and attach it to this link in the email, so that the link looks something like:

> "https://api.myapp.example.com/v1/users/verify?vt=12345"

Where `vt=12345` is the "verification token" (again likely a UUID). So the user clicks this link and my `GET v1/users/verify` endpoint looks at the token, somehow confirms its valid, and makes some DB updates to "activate" the user. They can now log in.

Similar scenarios for when a user wants to unsubscribe from receiving email, or when they can't remember their password and need to recover it so that they can log in.

#### Unsubscribe

User wants to stop receiving emails but still wants to use the app. They click an "*Unsubscribe*" link in a weekly newsletter we send them. This link needs to contain some kind of similar "unsubscribe token" that, like the verification token above, is generated + stored on the server, and is used to authenticate the user's request to unsubscribe from email.

#### Recover Password

Here the user has forgotten their password and needs to recover it. So at the login screen they click the "*Forgot my password*" link, and are presented with a form where they must fill out their email address. Server sends an email to that address. They check this email and it contains a link to a form where they can enter their new password. This link needs to contain a "reset password token" that -- like the verification token above -- is generated + stored on the server, and is used to authenticate the user's request to change their password.

So here we have three very similar problems to solve, all requiring the use of what I'm calling "*one-time only (OTO) security tokens*". These OTO tokens:

- Must be generated server-side and persisted (maybe to a `security_tokens` table)
- Must be something that can be attached to links that we'll expose from inside of emails
- Must only be valid one time: once they click it, the token is "used" and cannot be reused

### My question

The solution I came up was simple...almost too simple.

For the tokens I am just generating random UUIDs (36-char) and storing them to a `security_tokens` table that has the following fields:

```
[security_tokens]
---
id (PK)
user_id (FK to [users] table)
token (the token itself)
status (UNCLAIMED or CLAIMED)
generated_on (DATETIME when created)
```

When the server creates them they are "UNCLAIMED". When the user clicks a link inside the table they are "CLAIMED". A background worker job will run periodically to clean up any CLAIMED tokens or to delte any UNCLAIMED tokens that have "expired" (based on their `generated_on` fields). The app will also ignore any tokens that have been previously CLAIMED (and have just not yet been cleaned up).

I *think* this solution would work, but I'm not a super security guy and I'm worried that this approach:

1. Possibly leaves my app open to some type of attack/exploit; and
2. Possibly reinvents the wheel when some other solution might work just as well

Like for the 2nd one above I'm wondering if I should be using a hash/HMAC/JWT-related mechanism instead of a dead simple UUID. Maybe there's some smart crypto/security folks who found a way to make these tokens contain CLAIM status and expiration date themselves in a secure/immutable fashion, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You're on the right lines**

I have a very similar method in my application based on what I want it to do. I have a table containing each user (a Users table) which I can use to reference each individual account and perform actions based on their identity. There are a *lot* of security threats to mitigate by adding in user accounts and self-management options. Here's how I combat a few of these vulnerabilities.

**Verifying your email**

When a user signs up, the server should use the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider()` class to generate a random salt with sufficient length that it could never realistically be guessed. Then, I hash the salt (on it's own) and apply base64 encoding to it so that it can be added to a Url. Send the completed link to the user via email, and be sure to store that hash against the relevant `UserId` in the `Users` table.

The user sees a nice and neat "Click here to validate your email address" in their inbox and can click on the link. It should redirect to a page that accepts an optional url parameter (such as `mywebsite.com/account/verifyemail/myhash` and then check the hash server-side. The site can then check the hash against the activation hashes it has stored in the database. If it matches a record, then you should mark the `Users.EmailVerified` column to `true` and commit to the table. Then, you can delete that Verification record entry from the table.

Well done, you've successfully verified a user's email address is real!

**Reset password**

Here, we implement a similar method. But instead of a Verification record, we're better off storing our record in a PasswordResetRequest table, and do not delete records - this allows you to see whether or not a password was reset and when. Each time the user requests a password reset, you should display an anonymous message such as "An email was sent to your primary email address containing further instructions". Even if one was not sent or the account doesn't exist, it stops a potential attacker from enumerating usernames or email addresses to see if they are registered with your service. Again, if they are real, send a link using the same method as before.

The users opens their email address and clicks on the link. They are then redirected to a reset page such as `mywebsite.com/account/resetpassword/myhash`. The server then runs the hash in the url against the database and returns a result if it is real. Now, this is the tricky part - you shouldn't keep these active for long. I'd recommend a column linking the hash to the `Users.UserId`, one called `ExpiraryDateTime` which contains something like `Datetime.Now.AddMinutes(15)` (which makes it easier to work with later), and one called `IsUsed` as a boolean (false by default).

On clicking a link, you should check to see if a link exists. If not, give them them to the default "There was a problem with that link. Please request a new one" text. However, if the link is valid, you should check that `Used == false` because you don't want people using the same link more than once. If it's not used, great! Let's check to see if it's still valid. The easiest way would be a simple `if (PasswordResetRequest.ExpiraryDateTime < DateTime.Now)` - if the link is still valid, then you can proceed with the password reset. If not, it means it was generated a while ago and you shouldn't allow it to be used anymore. Seriously, some sites will still allow you to generate a link today and if your email is hacked 1 month from now, you can still use the reset links!

I should also mention that each time the user requests a password reset, you should check the existing records in the table for a **valid** link. If one is valid (meaning it can still be used) then you should instantly invalidate it. Replace the hash with some assistive text like "Invalid: User requested new reset link". This also lets you know they've requested more than one link whilst also invalidating their link. You could also mark it as Used if you really wanted to just to prevent people from trying to use expired links by being smart and sneaking the whole "Invalid: User requested new reset link" as an encoded URL into their browsers. You should never have more than one reset link active for the same account - **ever**!

**Unsubscribing**

For this, I'd have a simple flag in the database that determines whether or not a user can receive promotional offers and newsletters etc. So a `Users.SubscribedToNewsletter` would suffice. They should be able to log in and change this in their Email Settings or Communication Preferences etc.

**Some code examples**

This is my RNGCryptoServiceProvider code in C#

```
public static string GenerateRandomString(RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng, int size)
{
    var bytes = new Byte[size];

    rng.GetBytes(bytes);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
}

var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
var randomString = GenerateRandomSalt(rng, 47); // This will end up being a string of almost entirely random bytes
```

**Why do I use RNGCryptoServiceProvider?**

The `RNGCryptoServiceProvider()` (which is a C# class in their Security library) allows you to generate a seemingly random string of bytes based on entirely random and non-reproducable events. Classes like the `Random()` still need to use some sort of internal data to generate a number based on predictable algorithmic events such as current date and time. The `RNGCryptoServiceProvider()` uses things like cpu temperatures, number of running processes, etc. all to create something random that can't be reproduced. This allows for the final byte array to be as random as possible.

**Why do I Base64 encode it?**

Base64 encoding will result in a string containing only numbers and letters. This means there will be no symbols or encoded characters within the text and therefore it is safe to use in a URL. This isn't so much a security feature, but it does allow you to only allow numbers and letters within the parameters of the method, and filter out or reject any input that doesn't match this standard. For example, filtering out any inputs that contain the chevrons `<` and `>` should allow you to prevent XSS.

**Something to keep in mind**

You should ALWAYS assume that the link containing your hash is **invalid** until you perform each check on it to ensure it passes requirements. So you can do your various `if` statements but unless you pass **every single one**, you leave your default *next action* to some form of error for the user. To clarify, I should check that the password reset link is valid, then not used, then still within the time window, **and then** perform my reset actions. Should it fail to pass any of these requirements, the default action should be to give the user an error saying that it is an invalid link.

**Notes for others**

Since I'm pretty confident this isn't the *only* way to do this, I'd just like to declare that this is how I've done it for years which has never failed me and has gotten my company through several extensive pentests. But if someone has a better / more secure way of doing so, please do shed some light as I'd be happy to learn more. If you have any further questions or need clarification on a particular part I mentioned, just let me know and I'll try my best to help

Comment: Thanks @Horkrine (+1) - amazing + thoughtful answer!!! I follow everything you're saying here and just have two super-quick followup questions for you, if you don't mind! **(1)** Your method of generating a base64-encoded, `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`-salted hash vs my random UUID, what's the real security differential there? Is it just that salted-hashes are more difficult to guess/crack than 36-char UUIDs? And **(2)** Any chance you could update your answer with a quick snippet for how you generate your `RNGCryptoServiceProvider`-salted hashes and what language its in? Thanks again so much!!!

Comment: So, I've just realised this isn't under C#. I'll still edit the answer, but the code I put will be in C# - you should still be able to do something similar in whatever you're using though. I'll add my C# snippets for you, along with some links.

Comment: Edited. Please let me know if there's anything else you need

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again @Horkrine (+1). What about using JWT to do this? I could probably stuff the user id and the expiration date into the JWT's signed data, and the only drawback would be that tokens could be reused until they expire, which I think is OK for these 3 scenarios, no?

Comment: @Horkrine why does the last line read GenerateRandomSalt shouldn't it be GenerateRandomString?