# Creating base64 encoded random security tokens

Tags: c#, random, cryptography, token

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668353/how-can-i-generate-a-cryptographically-secure-pseudorandom-number-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, which now is somewhat old. Based on that, is this a viable way to create a random token today? I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48172412/11297850), where it seems the same approach is used.

```
private byte[] GetRandomBytes(int size)
{
    using (var randomNumberGenerator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
    {
        var randomBytes = new byte[size];
        randomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(randomBytes);

        return randomBytes;
    }
}

...

var randomBytes = GetRandomBytes(size);
var token = Convert.ToBase64String(randomBytes);
```

I intend to use the tokens as one-time tokens in URLs for multiple purposes like double opt-in and login. The lifetime of the tokens depends on the usage, but for e.g. login it's short, e.g. 5 minutes. There aren't any passwords involved, only the "magic link" mailed to the users e-mail.

The solution protected doesn't need the most bleeding edge protection, but I want it to be relativley difficult to guess a token and get in. If it is difficult to guess the token, and since I expire the tokens after n amount of time, is this a viable approach? And how difficult will it be to guess a token if someone already has a predefined list of Base64 encoded numbers?

Comment: `RandomNumberGenerator.Create()` returns a cryptographic strength RNG, so it will not be possible to guess the token unless you make it too small.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public string generateCipher()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            var rand = new Random();
            var bytes = new byte[32];
            rand.NextBytes(bytes);

            string symPass = 
        Convert.ToBase64String(bytes).Substring(1,32);
            var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime();
            var resd= timestamp / 100;

            string cipher = symPass+timestamp/100;


            return cipher ;
        }
```

Comment: `Random()` is a poor choice for this application. Adding the timestamp makes predicting the output even easier, perhaps even trivial.